# gsubで句読点とサ変接続を取り除く方法

Tags: r

RMeCabを使った形態素解析で、文章中の句読点（。　、）とサ変接続（”　’）を取り除く方法を教えて頂けませんでしょうか？下のコードを試したのですが、消すことができませんでした。

```
data_clean <- gsub('。', "", data)
data_clean <- gsub('、', "", data)
data_clean <- gsub(',', "", data)
data_clean <- gsub('"', "", data)
data_clean <- gsub(''', "", data)
```

Answer (score 1):

。や、には全角半角の両タイプがあるため除去漏れが生じているのではないでしょうか (Rは全角`。`と半角`｡`を区別します)。半角の`'`は`\'`と、`"`は`\"`と表記することでパターンに含める事ができます。なお、`gsub()`は`|`を用いることで複数のパターンを引数に取ることができます。

```
  # data例 (左から各記号の全角版・半角版が挟まっています、"を入れた都合で\が入っています)
x <- "あ。い｡う、え､お’か'き”く\"け"

　 # 全角半角両方の 。 、 ” ’ をパターンに指定し、除去
gsub(pattern = "。|｡|、|､|”|\"|’|\'", replacement = "", x)   # [1] "あいうえおかきくけ"

    # 正規表現を用いたパターンマッチ (@MichaelChirico様コメントありがとうございます)
   gsub(pattern = "[。｡、､”\"’\']", replacement = "", x)

library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, pattern = "。|｡|、|､|”|\"|’|\'", replacement = "")   # 同上

a <- str_extract_all(x, pattern = "\\p{Hiragana}|\\p{Katakana}|\\p{Han}")
paste(a[[1]], collapse = "")　　# 削除ではなく抽出で処理
```

Comment: `pattern = "[。｡、､”\"’\']"`だけでだいじょうぶじゃないでしょうか

Comment: @MichaelChirico; おっしゃる通り、それだけで大丈夫です。(深い理由があるわけではありませんが) 正規表現の使用を回避したため、このような解答となりました。コメントありがとうございます。